# Changing Notification sound in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode12

I was wondering if it's possible to change the local notification sound. I have an mp3 file called notifysound.mp3 and I added it to my assets file however, it does not work and the default sound gets triggered.

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct Alert: View {
    
    @State var noon = false
    
    
    func noonNotify() {
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Meds"
        content.subtitle = "Take your meds"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "notifysound.mp3"))
        
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 12
        dateComponents.minute = 00
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        
        // choose a random identifier
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        // add our notification request
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack {
            
            Toggle(isOn: $noon) {
                Text("Noon")
            }
            .onChange(of: Prime) { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    noonNotify()
                }
            }
            
            Button("Request Permission") {
                
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                    if success {
                        print("All set!")
                    } else if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
             
        }
    }
}
```

I tried renaming the file and adding the extension to the name, but nothing works. Would anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: Have you read this documentation page? The sounds have to be in specific formats and in specific locations: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP3 files are not supported. You need a wav, caf, or aiff less than 30 seconds long. More details in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound

Comment: i tried using .wac and .caf and still does not work

Comment: The sound file needs to be in your app bundle, and you refer to it with e.g. `UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName("mySound.wav"))`

Comment: app bundle as in my assets file?? or is an app bundle something else?

Comment: The app bundle is your built app and all its resources. Just add the sound file to your project and make sure it’s in your target’s “Copy Bundle Resources” build phase. 

(You can put sound files in your asset catalog, but it doesn’t look like UNNotificationSound has a way to load from there.)